# Using SEO friendly URLs in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am in a situation where I want to restructure my site's urls.  That is I have a page that lists the article names (with each article name as a link). As shown below:

> ARTICLE1
>
> ARTICLE2
>
> ARTICLE3

Now if I click on an article I want the url to be as follows:

> www.domain.com/ArticleID/name-of-the-Article

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term your looking for is "**url rewriting**" or "**routing**".

I think the easy way will be to use the ASP.NET MVC routing, it works with Webforms too:

[Using Routing With WebForms](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/11/using-routing-with-webforms.aspx)

[Routing with ASP.NET Web Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [URL Rewriting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx), I'd also recomend [UrlRewritingNet](http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html).

Answer (score 1):

Other possibilities that have worked well:

If your site is hosted on Windows Server 2008, you can use the Microsoft URL Rewrite Module for IIS 7.0.

A nice tool for older servers is Isapi Rewrite ([look here](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) - there's a free light version), very similar to Apache style mod_rewrite. May be a problem in shared hosting environments unless the provider is willing to install an Isapi dll.